# color in block hides text

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I have the following code, wicth I need to modify to include backgroud color, however when I do that the text is hidden. Could you help me soolve this issue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{pics/dbox/.style 2 args={code={%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\w}{max((width("#1")+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep})/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dbox/height}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}-height("#1")),%
(width("#2")+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep})/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dbox/height}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}-height("#2")))*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dbox/height}}
\path (-\w*1pt/2,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dbox/height}/2) 
 node[above right] (bl) {#2}
 rectangle
(\w*1pt/2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dbox/height}/2)
 node[below left] (tr) {#1};
 \node[pic actions,inner sep=0pt,fit=(bl)(tr),path picture={\path[pic actions]
 (path picture bounding box.north west)
 -- (path picture bounding box.south east);}] 
 (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dbox/name}){};
}},dbox/.cd,height/.initial=2cm,name/.initial=}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path pic[draw,fill=black!20] {dbox={abc}{qd0}} (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: with text:]

[image: when I add background color the text disapears:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a version in which you can set the style for the bottom left (`bl`) and top right (`tr`) corners to your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{pics/dbox/.style 2 args={code={%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\w}{max((width("#1")+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep})/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dbox/height}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}-height("#1")),%
(width("#2")+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep})/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dbox/height}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}-height("#2")))*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dbox/height}}
\path[/tikz/dbox/bl style]  (-\w*1pt/2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dbox/height}/2) |-
    (\w*1pt/2,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dbox/height}/2) -- cycle;
\path[/tikz/dbox/tr style]  (-\w*1pt/2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dbox/height}/2) -|
    (\w*1pt/2,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dbox/height}/2) -- cycle;
\path (-\w*1pt/2,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dbox/height}/2) 
 node[above right] (bl) {#2}
 rectangle
(\w*1pt/2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dbox/height}/2)
 node[below left] (tr) {#1};
 \node[pic actions,inner sep=0pt,fit=(bl)(tr),path picture={\path[pic actions]
 (path picture bounding box.north west)
 -- (path picture bounding box.south east);}] 
 (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/dbox/name}){};
}},dbox/.cd,height/.initial=2cm,name/.initial=,
bl style/.style={},tr style/.style={},
bl/.code={\tikzset{dbox/bl style/.style={#1}}},
tr/.code={\tikzset{dbox/tr style/.style={#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path  
 (0,0) pic[draw,dbox/.cd,bl={fill=black!20},tr={fill=black!20}] {dbox={abc}{qd0}} 
 (3,0) pic[draw,dbox/.cd,bl={fill=blue!20},tr={fill=red!20}] {dbox={abc}{qd0}} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]